# compact $p$-adic Lie group can be embedded into $O_K^n$ or $\text{GL}_n(K)$?

Tags: lie-groups, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups, local-fields, non-archimedean-fields

Let $K$ be a local field of charecteristic $0$ and $G$ be a compact $p$-adic Lie group of dimension $n$, then can $G$ be embedded into $O_K^n$ or $\text{GL}_n(K)$ as a closed subgroup? This is a dual question for the real case.

Recall that a $p$-adic Lie group is a manifold with a locally analytic group structure and a manifold is a topological space which is locally isomorphism to an open set in $K^n$. These definitions are in Schneider's book on $p$-adic Lie group.

I am more interested in the case of $n=1$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, such that I can embed $G$ into $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.

Thanks!

Comment: Given a compact $p$-adic Lie group $G$, you can always embed it in $GL_d(Z_p)$ for $d$ large enough. Since $G$ is a $p$-adic Lie group, it has an open subgroup $H$ that is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $GL_k(Z_p)$ for some $k$. This is one of several equivalent definitions of a $p$-adic Lie group. If $G$ is moreover compact, then $H$ has finite index in $G$. The group $H$ has a faithful $k$-dimensional representation $V$, and you can now induce it to $G$ to get a faithful finite dimensional representation of $G$.

Comment: So is your question about controlling the $n$ such that $G$ embeds in $GL_n(Z_p)$ or $GL_n(O_K)$ in terms of $dim(G)$? This is not going to work since for a fixed $K$, $GL_n(O_K)$ has a small torsion subgroup, while a compact $p$-adic Lie group of dimension $d$ can have any finite torsion subgroup you like.

Comment: No, because an $n$-dimensional Lie algebra cannot be embedded in $\mathrm{GL}_n$ in general (nor even $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}$), there are nilpotent counterexamples (first due to Yves Benoist for $n+1$ but maybe $n$ is much easier). At the positive side known bounds for Ado's theorem are pretty bad (exponential I think).

Comment: But any finite group $F$ is a $0$-dimensional compact $p$-adic Lie group and clearly can't be  (unless $F=1$) embedded in $GL_0(\mathrm{Q}_p)=1$. Similarly if $F$ is non-abelian (or abelian and non-cyclic) then the 1-dimensional compact $p$-adic group $F\times \mathbf{Z}_p$ can't be embedded into the abelian group $GL_1(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. Could you edit the question to avoid such trivial counterexamples? My previous comment shows something less obvious: for large $n$ there exists an $n$-dimensional compact $p$-adic Lie group such that no open subgroup embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.